# Export MapInfo Plan to DXF

Tags: export, mapinfo, dwg

I would like to export a plan from MapInfo into DWG format. This exported DWG will be used by a laser cutter to engrave the vector outlines into wood.

I'm aware of the Universal Translator tool included within MapInfo but this tool only converts a single layer to an individual DWG file. I would like to complete the same process but convert a complete Plan view into  a single DWG file.

Is there a way in MapInfo to export a full plan as DWG, if not what other combinations of software could I use to create the same output?

Comment: or open this mapinfo and export as DWG in QGIS.

Comment: you can use this online converter to go from MapInfo (TAB) to DWG from safe software http://demos.fmeserver.com/easytranslator/index.html

Comment: Will either of those suggestions allow me to export my whole plan (including the layers, frames, scale bar etc.) to a single DWG file?

Comment: try it and see.

Comment: Both options would only convert a single layer to a DWG file, in the same way the MapInfo Universal Translator does. I'm looking for a method of save a whole map as a single DWG.

Comment: do you have a sample of the file?

Comment: I don't believe a sample of the data will be beneficial since the suggestions provided above only relate to the translation of a single layer into DXF format.I am not looking to achieve this, I'm interested to know whether it is possible to export a whole layout of many layers into a single combined DXF file.

Comment: I am not familiar with current versions of MapInfo. But you may want to examine the following approach: Export from MapInfo as AI (Adobe Illustrator). Then convert this file to DXF with another program.